# How to save QListView items to file

Tags: c++, qt4

How to save QListView items to text file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access the elements via the underlying Item Model and write them to the file in whatever way makes sense in the context of your program.

---

EDIT for more detail:

I'm a little rusty in my Qt experience right now, so I don't have an exact snippet of code. Furthermore, there's probably more than one way to go about doing this.

Every Qt View is attached to an associated model derived from QAbstractItemModel. (If you don't know how that Model/View stuff works, they you ought to read over some of their documentation, such as [here](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/model-view-programming.html).)

Generally, I would expect the derived model class to have some convenient functions for getting at the data. For instance, [QStringListModel](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qstringlistmodel.html) has a member for getting the data as a QStringList. So the easiest way to get the data depends on the actual model class being used in your particular application.

Otherwise, you could ask the the view for its model through [model()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qabstractitemview.html#model) and then ask that for each piece of data through [data()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qabstractitemmodel.html#data).

Comment: Can you provide piece of code how to get QListView items to QStringList?

Comment: Edited to add more detail about that.